# Problems with extending regular Objects to support ES5 Array capabilities

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-6

I have long ago been willing to get the line between native Arrays and regular Objects totally blurred, not only extending Object with the same capabilities as Arrays got in ES5, but bundle up with my custom package of methods on both sides.

Couple of smart people thought about these paradigm changes. Like Angus Croll mentioned it in the article [javascript-object-keys-finally](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/28/javascript-object-keys-finally/):

> "Moreover as the line between Arrays and regular Objects blurs (aided
>   by custom getters and setters) we’re likely to see a growth in generic
>   “array-like” objects which enjoy the best of both worlds – non-numeric
>   identifiers and access to the rich API set defined by Array.prototype.
>   EcmaScript 5 has apparently pre-empted this trend by introducing the
>   generic method, defined by one type but useable by any."

Along the way, he get things coded in the article:
[extending-objects-with-javascript-getters](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/11/15/extending-objects-with-javascript-getters/)

```
function extendAsArray(obj) {
    if (obj.length === undefined || obj.__lookupGetter__('length')) {
        var index = 0;
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if(!obj.__lookupGetter__(prop)) {
                (function(thisIndex, thisProp) {
                    obj.__defineGetter__(thisIndex, function() {return obj[thisProp]});
                })(index, prop)
                index++;
            }
        };
        obj.__defineGetter__("length", function() {return index});
    }
    return obj;
}

var myObj = {
    left:50,
    top:20,
    width:10,
    height:10
}

extendAsArray(myObj);

[].map.call(myObj,function(s){return s+' px'}).join(', '); 
//"50px ,20px ,10px, 10px"
```

This approach is exceptionally interesting for me. However, it is also seemingly suffering a couple of serious problems!

1. How about extending the original myObj model with a couple of new properties?
   Should we run `extendAsArray` on every property change to update it's concerning `length` property?
2. When a property changes, it's not just the `length` property that's relevant;
   the array indices should also be updated, because an array-like property request definitely turns out to be undefined. So when

   ```
   console.log(myObj.length) -> 4
   myObj.zAxis=0
   ```

   then

   ```
   console.log(myObj[4]) // -> undefined!
   console.log(myObj.length) // -> 4!
   ```

I have modified Angus' code accordingly, so it supports automatic update of `length` property on request:

```
function extendAsArray(obj) {
    var index = 0;
    for(var prop in obj){
        if(!obj.__lookupGetter__(prop)){
           (function(thisIndex, thisProp){
              Object.defineProperty(obj, thisIndex, {
                    get: function(){return obj[thisProp]}
                    , enumerable: true
                    , configurable: true
                    , writeable: true
              });
           })(index, prop)
           index++;
        }
    }
    if(!obj.__lookupGetter__('length')){
       Object.defineProperty(obj, 'length', {
          get: function(){
            return extendAsArray(obj);
          }
          , configurable: true
          , writeable: true
       });
       return obj;
    }
    else{
       return index;
    }
}
```

The problem is: how do we updating the object's array indices together with its `length` property when a property is changed, added or removed?

Should I use `Object.watch`?

And there is still an unsolved question: how to interfere with my own unshimmed utility library, having made it also for Objects in a consistent way?

I am using the same codebase for both types: `z.Object({}).mapEvery` does the same as `z.Object([]).mapEvery`

Please avoid mentioning JQuery, and Underscore as well. I have got a comprehensive, custom list of methods for both types, and I am willing to use the standards completed possibly with my unshimmed ones, and I am not willing to refactor it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library watch.js out there, which is watching out for either property updates or new property addition as well.
[try out!](http://jsfiddle.net/NjNJt/)

It is working with setInterval, so it is not performance-friendly however.

When Harmony is out, we can do things that simply:

```
Object.observe(obj,Observer);
```

Check the spec for that:
[Harmony](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aobserve)

But, when later object extension is not in focus, i can freeze up the whole object upon initialization, not to be bothered with neither property changes nor property addition.

The code is changed accordingly:

```
extendAsArray = function z_extendAsArray(obj){
    var index = 0;
    for(var prop in obj){
        if(!obj.__lookupGetter__(prop)){
           (function(thisIndex, thisProp){
              Object.defineProperty(obj, thisIndex, {
                    get: function(){return obj[thisProp]}
                    , enumerable: true
                    , configurable: true
                    , writeable: true
              });
           })(index, prop)
           index++;
        }
    }
    if(!obj.__lookupGetter__('length')){
       Object.defineProperty(obj, 'length', {
        value:index
       });
       if(!Object.freeze){
          Object.defineProperty(Object, "freeze", {
                enumerable: false
              , configurable: false
              , writable: false
              , value: function (obj) {
                  var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
                  for(var i=0; i<props.length; i++){
                      var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj,props[i]);
                      if("value" in desc ){
                         desc.writable = false;
                      }
                      desc.configurable = false;
                      Object.defineProperty( obj, props[i], desc );
                  }
                  return Object.preventExtensions(obj);
              }
          });
       }
       Object.freeze(obj);
    }
    return obj;
};
```

Also i have found out what Angus Croll, who has been mentioned by the previous post has talked about it.

"Yes, we can make use of the equivalent functionality offered by well written libraries like underscore.js, but still we’re locked into non-standard, inverted signatures in which methods are static and objects are merely extra arguments – an ungainly arrangement for an instance-only language. At some point all supported browsers will be ES5 compliant, at which point the shimmed codebase can simply remove it’s shim library and carry on, while the unshimmed one must choose between a major refactor or a perpetually non-standard and static utility library."

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is your question:

> how do we updating the object's array indices together with its length property when a property is changed, added or removed?

You create methods to do it, so you essentially mimic the [Object internal methods](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12). I don't think you can do that with getters and setters, but I may be wrong about that.

The rest is more of a comment than an answer.

> I have long ago been willing to get the line between native Arrays and regular Objects totally blurred

The line is already totally blurred. Arrays are Objects, the only thing that sets them apart is their special length property.

> EcmaScript 5 has apparently pre-empted this trend by introducing the generic method,

ES5 didn't introduce generic methods, they have been in the language since ed 3 at least.

> defined by one type but useable by any

Not at all, in fact ES5 is more restrictive. In ed 3, `call` and `apply` coerce the *thisArg* to an object using `Object(*thisArg*)`, or substitute the global object if nothing was passed. Not so in ES5 which passes *thisArg* unmodified.

The restriction on using arrays as objects is related to convention, not the language itself. Most developers see a clear divide between when an object or array should be used. There are few cases where you really need to use an array like an object, but no doubt they exist. jQuery is an example of where an Object leverages Array properties, e.g. the elements collected by a selector are added as numeric properties and there is a length property that is the number of elements. That way generic array methods can be applied to jQuery objects (all in ed 3, by the way).

The `Object.watch` method is in JavaScrpit™, it's not part of ES5 so use with caution.

A major problem with creating your own version of built–in objects is that you'll probably end up wrapping every built–in method in a native one (like jQuery wraps every DOM method pretty much) and start setting getters and setters on every property, or end up with function calls to replace property access (e.g. jQuery's `val`, `attr` and `prop` methods). Rather tedious, and slow if performance matters.

Oh sorry, I mentioned jQuery… :-(

It just seems to be more sensible to design a library or framework to make the best use of the features that the language has, rather than trying to force it to do things it doesn't do well, or does not do natively.

But full marks for trying. :-)

Comment: The difference between Objects and Arrays are more than just the Array's length property.
As far as i know :-) there is a couple of ES5 enumerable methods like map,filter being added to recent browsers, however IE9 also supports it.
These methods are totally out of reach from native Objects.

Comment: Both [*map*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19) and [*filter*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20) are in ES5, they are both "intentionally generic" do not "require that [their] this value be an Array object", so they will work on any native object with suitable properties. They are not required to work with host objects (but do for DOM objects in many browsers though).

Comment: @ZoltanLudanyi—what is the purpose of the link? Arrays inherit from Array.prototype, but the methods are mostly generic and can be applied to any object using call or apply. So it's possible to create Objects that behave like Arrays. The only difficulty is the special length property, but if the object is sufficiently abstracted, access to the length property can be controlled to ensure it behaves. Hence enumerable.js "works".

Comment: Think first:
alert([].map.call({head:15,title:30},function(s){return s+'px'}).
         join(', ')); ->prints ''
It does not work!
though:
var o={foo:"foo"}
Array.push(o, 'foo');
Array.push(o, bar);
alert( o.toSource() );//prints:({foo:"foo", length:1, 1:"bar"})
It works!
Both are generic ES5 Array call on Object.
It is not inherited from prototype, it is a static method of Array!
But object doesn't augment this method without "tricks".
But providing a trick turned out to be more exhaustive.
http://slid.es/zludany/enumerablejs

Comment: It doesn't work because you have to give the object a length property and the property names must be numbers (read the algorithm in the spec). If you fix those issues, then: 
`[].map.call({0:'head',1:'title',length:2},function(s){return s+'px'}).join(', '))` returns `headpx, titlepx`. Perhaps you want an `Object.prototype.map` function to visit enumerable own properties.

Comment: Object.prototype is forbidden man!!!
AND
You simply can not read as well.
First, the quotes are made by Angus Croll, not me!!!
Second, in this question http://goo.gl/ot213 i promoted my solution which does automatically what you describe!
Look:
for (var prop in obj) {
            if(!obj.__lookupGetter__(prop)) {
                (function(thisIndex, thisProp) {
                    obj.__defineGetter__(thisIndex, function() {return obj[thisProp]});
                })(index, prop)
                index++;
            }
        };

But this is also not satisfiable for a couple of reasons!

Comment: Here is a more standard compliance version of my example, in this post, mentioned above, as getters, __defineGetter__, __lookupGetter__ are about to be deprecated:
http://jsbin.com/epuzos/14/edit

Comment: I think we are talking past each other. Your original statement was about Arrays not being just objects with a special length. Perhaps not strictly true, but in practicality it is. Sure, arrays inherit a bunch of methods from Array.prototype but my point is that those methods are mostly generic and can be applied to any native (and many host) object. The only difficulty is dealing with the *length* property. In contrast, consider a Date object. None of Date.prototype's methods are generic, so it can't be said (for example) that a date is just an object with a special *timeValue* property.